# n_classes order in LinearSVC.coef_

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm working with LinearSVC to classify text data into 3 classes. The input data is the tfidf scores per word. I'm interested in seeing the "contribution" that words make to the classification. The first question is can I use the coef_ for this? The documentation states:

> coef_ : array, shape = [n_features] if n_classes == 2 else [n_classes, n_features]

So, I'm assuming then that "n_classes" corresponds to each of the 3 classes into which the documents can be classified, and the n_features are the coefficient values for my tfidf features. Assuming that is the case, what's the order of classes in coef_? How can I match each row in the array to one of my classes?

thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without digging into the source code, I believe there are two answers to your questions:

1. The classes are sorted. So if you have classes ['a', 'b', 'C'], then your class order would be ['C','a','b']. (This may look odd, but make that list in Python and .sort() it. That's the order.)
2. There is a mostly undocumented class member, `LinearSVC().classes_`, which holds the order used by the class (see [this method documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html#sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.decision_function)).