# LinearSVC coef_ attirbute

Tags: python, scikit-learn, coefficients, svc

I trained a LinearSVC model with the sklearn library in Python. The target variable `y` had 4 levels (`0,1,2,3`).

```
model = LinearSVC()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = tts(X, y, test_size = 0.25,
                                       random_state = 4)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
model.coef_
```

I get a NumPy ndarray like this:

```
array([[ -1.64280582,  -0.49711136,   0.        , ...,   0.        ,
         -0.50203059,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,   0.        ,  -2.67396495, ...,   2.35298657,
          0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  1.11471827,   3.76220356,   0.        , ..., -11.09758616,
          0.        ,   0.        ],
       [  0.        ,  -2.7305259 ,   0.09663903, ...,   0.        ,
          0.        ,   0.        ]])
```

I need to know which array matches each target variable level. How can I know that?

Comment: let me know if my answer helps

Answer (score 1):

**First**, this is a **one-vs-the-rest** implementation.

From the documentation:

> coef_ : array, shape = [n_features] if n_classes == 2 else [n_classes,
>   n_features] Weights assigned to the features (coefficients in the
>   primal problem). This is only available in the case of a linear
>   kernel.
>
> coef_ is a readonly property derived from raw_coef_ that follows the
>   internal memory layout of liblinear.

**In your case, the shape is [n_classes, n_features].**

- **`model.coef_[0,:]` gives you the feature's weights for class `0 vs all`.**
- **`model.coef_[1,:]` gives you the feature's weights for class `1 vs all`.**
- e.t.c.

Comment: Does 'class 0 vs. all' means that class 0 features' weights are the first number of every vector of model.coef_[0,:]?

Answer (score 0):

This array is in the same order as your input data. The array starts from [0] and this corresponds to your feature_1 in your input data. 
Structure of this array will be n_classes * n_features.

Comment: And the class order corresponds to the order that it first appears in y_train?

Comment: Found an answer to that question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30923147/n-classes-order-in-linearsvc-coef